# Cordova plugin in a Xamarin project

Tags: cordova, xamarin.forms

Is it possible to use a cordova plugin that was created in a xamarin android/ios project?

Request you to please share me the source available on internet if there are any. Thanks

Comment: This is a horrible idea , Its building 2 hybrid apps(cordova and xamarin) into 1 native app(android or ios) .. I think you should read the docs to improve your understanding on cordova and xamarin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. However, you can achieve something similar in Xamarin by building your app's UI using embedded HTML/JS/CSS and rendering it with the native browser control for each platform. I don't think this is a great solution, but if you really want to achieve maximum code sharing between platforms, and don't have an incredibly complex UI, this might be something worth considering.

For more infomation see: [WebView Documentation in Xamarin.Forms](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview/)

Comment: Thank you Wilson. Ill try this